# how to display a site into android webview without footer and header

Tags: android, html

i need to display another website into my android webview without it's header and footer

```
       wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
             wb.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +"document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " + "})()");
        }
        });
        wb.loadUrl(url);
        setContentView(wb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `iframe`?

Try something like this -

```
String iframe = "<iframe scrolling=\"no\" src=\"YOUR URL\"" +
"width=\"400px\" height=\"300\"></iframe>";

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //be sure to enable this or
                                                  //page might not load properly

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", iframe, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
//loading iframe
```

You can customize the iframe code according to your needs. Be sure to add `\` before every `"` in your **HTML Code**.

Comment: url is an webpage someone else so iframe also will show that site header

Comment: Yes it will but you have to adjust it's dimensions properly